# I want to join a word to an number to an cell value if it satisfei this particular condition?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table like this:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦══════╦════════╗
║ Arcticle ║ Issue ║ Test ║ Result ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬══════╬════════╣
║ AA       ║    22 ║ ABC  ║ YES    ║
║ AA       ║    24 ║ BAC  ║ NO     ║
║ AA       ║    25 ║ HHH  ║ YES    ║
║ AA       ║    27 ║ JJJ  ║ NO     ║
║ AA       ║    22 ║ SSS  ║ YES    ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩══════╩════════╝
```

Output should looks like this:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦══════╦════════╦════════════════╗
║ Arcticle ║ Issue ║ Test ║ Result ║     output     ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬══════╬════════╬════════════════╣
║ AA       ║    22 ║ ABC  ║ YES    ║ PASS Issue 22  ║
║ AA       ║    24 ║ BAC  ║ NO     ║ FAIL Issue 24  ║
║ AA       ║    25 ║ HHH  ║ YES    ║ PASS Issue 25  ║
║ AA       ║    27 ║ JJJ  ║ NO     ║ FAIL Issue 27  ║
║ AA       ║    22 ║ SSS  ║ YES    ║ PASS Issue 22  ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩══════╩════════╩════════════════╝
```

I have been used the code below, but it does not work, it return a mismatch error. I have understood that it can be a definition error for formulaes, but I don't know how to sort it out.

```
rangeval = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
a = "ISSUE"
c = "PASS"
d = "FAIL"
For i = 2 To rangeval
  b = Cells(i, 2).Value        
    If Cells(i, 4).Value = "YES" Then
        Cells(i, 5).Value = c+a+b
    Else
        Cells(i, 5).Value = d+a+b
    End If
Next i
```

Thanks for your effort and help.

Comment: + is addition, & is concatenate.  I'd also cstr(b), for 2 lines of code for IF's you can also use IIF(conditon, true, flaso) so cells(i,5).value =iif(Cells(i, 4).Value = "YES",c&a&cstr(b),d&a&cstr(b))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "+" i tried using "&" it worked thank you all for the effort

```
rangeval = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

a = "ISSUE"

c = "PASS"

d = "FAIL"

For i = 2 To rangeval

  b = Cells(i, 2).Value


    If Cells(i, 4).Value = "YES" Then

        Cells(i, 5).Value = c&a&b

    Else

        Cells(i, 5).Value = d&a&b

    End If

Next i
```